# Module Tensorflow has no attribute KMeans

Tags: python, tensorflow, k-means

I'm using Tensorflow for calculating DELF features.
I'm using next example from tensorflow models:
[github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/delf/delf/python/detect_to_retrieve/cluster_delf_features.py).

So there is a line here:

```
kmeans = tf.estimator.experimental.KMeans(...)
```

But I have no such model:

> AttributeError: module
>   'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api.estimator.experimental' has
>   no attribute 'KMeans'

My configuration:
tensorboard               1.13.1           py37hf484d3e_0
tensorflow                1.13.1          gpu_py37hc158e3b_0
tensorflow-base           1.13.1          gpu_py37h8d69cac_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                     py_0
tensorflow-gpu            1.13.1               h0d30ee6_0

---

Looks like this model replaced, but I can't find where.

Comment: did you mean this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeans?

Comment: @Vishal You are right - I tried `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering()` and it works. Right your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to use KMeans from tensorflow is

```
tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering()
```

For parameters and more information, read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeans).

Comment: Also, if you have some expirience on using KMeans in Tensorflow, maybe you can help me on another problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337848/cannot-change-number-of-clusters-in-kmeansclustering-tensorflow

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Ok. I will look into it and if I will get an answer, then will post there.